# Run two Commands when you hit a Tkinter Button

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I would like a Tkinter button to clear my current Grid, and also go to a function, and I cannot think of how to do it. I have a grid that is a menu, and in another function I have the code for what was just opened by hitting the button.

in short I want a button, when clicked to do this: `self.studyGuide` and this: `self.frame.grid_forget`.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self,master):

        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.grid()

        self.sg = Button(frame, text = "Study Guide", command = self.buttonStart, fg="red")
        self.sg.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

        self.quizlet = Button(frame, text = "Quizlet", command = self.quizlet)
        self.quizlet.grid(row = 2, column = 2)

        self.flashcard = Button(frame, text = "Flash Cards", command = self.flashcard)
        self.flashcard.grid(row = 2, column = 3)

        self.quitButton = Button(frame, text = "Quit", command = frame.quit)
        self.quitButton.grid(row = 3, column = 2)

        self.text = Label(frame, text = "Social Studies Study Tool")
        self.text.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

        def buttonStart(frame):
        self.studyGuide()
        self.frame.grid_forget()

   def studyGuide(self):
        studyGuide = Frame()
        studyGuide.pack()

        self.sgText = Label(studyGuide, text = "This is not real.")
        self.sgText.pack()
def quizlet(self):
        print("Quizlet")

def flashcard(self):
        print("Flashcards")

root = Tk()

app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Seems easy enough.  The callack you pass to `command` just needs to call both of the other functions.  What are you having trouble with specifically?  If you explain the _problem_ you're having with this task (maybe with a code snippet that demonstrates your problem), we'll be in a better position to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Simply, have the callback passed to the `Button` constructor call the other 2 functions:

```
def foo(self):
    self.studyGuide()
    self.frame.grid_forget()

root = Tk()
my_button = Button(root, text="I'm doing stuff", command=foo)
```

Comment: When I do that I get this error: `AttributeError: 'App' object has no attribute 'frame'`

Comment: I don't know what your code it, so I cannot tell you. If you edit your question with some code, I can try to figure it out for you.

Comment: You don't have the `self` keyword when you create `frame`. Change `frame = Frame(master)` to `self.frame = Frame(master)` and that should fix it for you.

Comment: This answer gives the right idea, but the example code is flawed. You aren't including `self` as an argument, so in the body of `foo` it will be undefined.